# option values in bootstrap select are displayed outside the dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-select, bootstrap-selectpicker

I'm facing an issue at times in my html page where all the options in the bootstrap-select are displayed outside the dropdown box. (attached the screenshot) 
dropdown

[image]

This issue is only observed sometimes. The values are getting populated from an api call.
This is my bootstrap-select css and js reference:
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.4/css/bootstrap-select.min.css,
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.4/js/bootstrap-select.js

Below are my code snippets.

```js
$.ajax({
  url: serverName + "api/v1/get/countrylist",
  type: 'GET',
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Authorization": "Basic " + basicKey,
    "x-access-token": xAccessToken

  },
  success: function(response){
    // console.log("visa-response: "+ response);
    var countryArr = [];
  response.forEach(function(item){
    countryArr.push({"country": item.country, "fee": item.fee});
    // console.log("my country " + item.country)
  })
  //console.log("countryArr-response: "+ countryArr[1].country);
  countryArr.forEach(function(item){
    $('.select-country .country-list').append('<option class="'+item.fee + '"' +'data-tokens="'+ item.country+'">' + item.country +'</option>')
  })
 
  $('.selectpicker').selectpicker();
  },
  error: function (exception) {
    console.log(exception);
  }
});
```

```html
  <div class="col-md-6 select-country">



                            <div class="customer-country text-center" >
                                <label style="margin-right:10px;"><strong>Select Your Country:</strong></label>
                                <select class="selectpicker country-list"  data-live-search="true" data-width="auto" data-style="btn-success" data-dropup-auto="false" standard title="Select Country...">

                                </select>

                            </div>
```

Comment: Can you provide the screenshot or more code? It doesn't seems to have enough code to troubleshoot

Comment: added the screenshot..

Answer (score 2):

So, when you use selectpicker class, it will create button element siblings with your select element with the **SAME CLASS**. So, when you target only class, it will update both of them. Use the selector: $(select.country-list) in the append section. It will only update the select element. It works for me.

```js
$.ajax({
        url: serverName + "api/v1/get/countrylist",
        type: 'GET',
        headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
                "Authorization": "Basic " + basicKey,
                "x-access-token": xAccessToken

        },
        success: function(response){
             // console.log("visa-response: "+ response);
                var countryArr = [];
        response.forEach(function(item){
                countryArr.push({"country": item.country, "fee": item.fee});
             // console.log("my country " + item.country)
        })
        //console.log("countryArr-response: "+ countryArr[1].country);
        countryArr.forEach(function(item){
                $('select.country-list').append('<option class="'+item.fee + '"' +'data-tokens="'+ item.country+'">' + item.country +'</option>')
        })
    
        $('.selectpicker').selectpicker();
        },
        error: function (exception) {
                console.log(exception);
        }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like bootstrap-select have to be re-render and refreshed when the options are loaded dynamically

```
$('.selectpicker').selectpicker('render');
$('.selectpicker').selectpicker('refresh');
```

Try adding this 2 lines at the last line of success function callback

Comment: i still faces the issues even after adding this